# Can't find Docker image on GCP

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, containers

I have a Docker container with Python code, and I'm trying to run it on the Google Cloud Platform. When I list the Docker images on GCP, I get

```
(erudite-stratum-222517)$ docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
```

With no images listed.

As far as I understand, the container was successfully pushed to GCP:

```
docker push eu.gcr.io/erudite-stratum-222517/first_test
The push refers to repository [eu.gcr.io/erudite-stratum-222517/first_test]
0ef83288f52f: Layer already exists 
3f3b6e2a9fe0: Layer already exists 
d8e1c4e9af76: Layer already exists 
6680c03f0d88: Layer already exists 
515fff016870: Layer already exists 
2f4f74d3821e: Layer already exists 
9978d084fd77: Layer already exists 
1191b3f5862a: Layer already exists 
08a01612ffca: Layer already exists 
8bb25f9cdc41: Layer already exists 
f715ed19c28b: Layer already exists 
latest: digest: sha256:3b4bf5f137acbf173a2c0dafb158090135e659e7b11a94d7726dc880fdefe203             
size: 2636
```

Is there a bug or am I doing something wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Where did you run the `docker image` command? From what machine is the output? I would guess you have to pull the image first with `docker pull eu.gcr.io/erudite-stratum-222517/first_test:latest`. Did you try that?

Comment: That was easy! Problem solved, thanks heaps!